# Optimising code to avoid hitting AppsScript time limit in GoogleSheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I have the following code that I have been trying to optimize avoid hitting the 6 minute time limits imposed by Google (Exceeded maximum execution time Error). It works pretty well on small data sets but when it comes to larger sets it really starts to struggle.

I'm not sure if there's anything I'm missing here or any other workarounds that could be implemented ?

Also could the use of the Google Sheets API help me in anyway currently in working with larger datasets? this script is only running in the built-in Apps Script tied to the actual document.

This is what I have tried at the moment although not sure if executed well,

- Utilizing batch operations
- Creating a dictionary
- Reading only the necessary columns
- Utilizing arrays.
- Batch multiple API calls into a single API call.

```
function populatespc() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sponsored Products Campaigns');
  var sheet60 = ss.getSheetByName('60 Day Sponsored Products Campaigns');

  // Read only necessary columns
  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 46).getValues();
  var data60 = sheet60.getRange(1, 1, sheet60.getLastRow(), 46).getValues();

  var identifiers = {
    'Campaign': [3, 5],
    'Bidding Adjustment': [3, 31],
    'Ad Group': [3, 4],
    'Product Ad': [3, 4, 6],
    'Product Targeting': [3, 4, 8],
    'Keyword': [3, 4, 7]
  };

  var header = data[0];
  var newHeader = header.concat(header.slice(35, 46).map(function(h) { return '60 Day ' + h; }));
  data[0] = newHeader;

  // Insert new columns
  sheet.insertColumnsAfter(46, 11);

  var dict60 = {};
  for (var i = 1; i < data60.length; i++) {
    var row60 = data60[i];
    var entity = row60[1];
    var ids = identifiers[entity];
    if (!ids) continue;
    var key = ids.map(function(col) { return row60[col]; }).join('|');
    dict60[key] = row60;
  }

  var output = data.map(function(row, i) {
    if (i === 0) return newHeader;

    var entity = row[1];

    if (entity === 'Campaign Negative Keyword' || entity === 'Negative Keyword') {
      return row.concat(Array(11).fill(''));
    }

    var ids = identifiers[entity];
    if (!ids) {
      return row.concat(Array(11).fill(''));
    }

    var newRow = row.concat(Array(11).fill(''));

    var key = ids.map(function(col) { return row[col]; }).join('|');
    var row60 = dict60[key];
    if (row60) {
      newRow = row.concat(row60.slice(35, 46));
    }

    return newRow;
  });

  // Write only new columns
  sheet.getRange(1, 47, output.length, 11).setValues(output.map(function(row) { return row.slice(46); }));

}
```

Comment: Anything to do with the ui like inserting or hiding/showing columns can be quite slow

Comment: Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for testing your showing script?

Comment: `larger sets` Would you describe what you understand by a "larger" set.

Comment: I would describe it of a sheet with about 50k+ worth of rows

Comment: I would share but unfortunately it has sensitive information, but in essence the script is performing a lookup based on identifiers and rows in another sheet that match the identifiers have some of their columns imported over.

Answer (score 0):

The spreadsheet content might affect the script performance due to the spreadsheet recalculation done on the server side when spreadsheet structure and data are read and written / changed by the SpreadsheeApp service.

One option is to simplify your spreadsheet complexity. Another option is to use the Advanced Spreadsheet Service instead of the Spreadsheet Service.

Comment: What kind of benefits does the Advanced Spreadsheet Service provide ? I assume this would require using the Google Sheets API